# need help debugging prolog

Tags: debugging, prolog, gnu-prolog

Im a college student I have minimal knowledge in prolog so any help is appreciated. The error i am getting is " uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,name/2) " below i will have every place where "name" shows up in my code

```
parse_square(Square, File-Rank) :-
    name(Square, [F,R]),
    name(File, [F]),
    myname(Rank, [R]),
    on_board(File-Rank).
 
parse_move(Move, From_File-From_Rank, To_File-To_Rank) :-
    name(Move, [FF,FR,TF,TR]),
    name(From_File, [FF]),
    myname(From_Rank, [FR]),
    name(To_File, [TF]),
    myname(To_Rank, [TR]),
    on_board(From_File-From_Rank),
    on_board(To_File-To_Rank).

drawCell(BoardStates, Row, Col) :-
  pair(Name, Col),
  myMember(piece(Name-Row, Color, Piece), BoardStates),
  drawSymbol(' ', 1),
  (
    (Color == black, drawSymbol('*', 1));
    (Color == white, drawSymbol(' ', 1))
  ),
  pair(Piece, PieceAbbreviation),
  drawSymbol(PieceAbbreviation, 1),
  drawSymbol(' ', 1).

% deals with white space
drawCell(BoardStates, Row, Col) :-
  pair(Name, Col),
  \+ (myMember(piece(Name-Row, Color, Piece), BoardStates)),
  drawSymbol(' ', 4).
```

Any help here is appreciated. And there is a good chance there will be more errors after this